# python - sort a list of tuple in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
{'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b'))],
         'B1': [(3, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (1, ('c', 'd'))]},
 'BBB': {'A1': [(4, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (1, ('a', 'b'))],
         'B1': [(3, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (1, ('a', 'b'))]}}
```

I want to order by the first element in the list of tuple of tuple.

Desired result:

```
{'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('a', 'b'))]},
 'BBB': {'A1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (4, ('a', 'b'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the lists in place using the `list.sort` method

```
d = {'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b'))],
             'B1': [(3, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (1, ('c', 'd'))]},
     'BBB': {'A1': [(4, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (1, ('a', 'b'))],
             'B1': [(3, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (1, ('a', 'b'))]}}

for subd in d.values():
    for l in subd.values():
        l.sort()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)

{'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('a', 'b'))]},
 'BBB': {'A1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (4, ('a', 'b'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))],
             'B1': [(1, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]},
     'BBB': {'A1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (4, ('a', 'b'))],
             'B1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]}}
new_d = {a:{c:sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]) for c, d in b.items()} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'AAA': {'A1': [(0, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('c', 'd')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]},
 'BBB': {'A1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('c', 'd')), (4, ('a', 'b'))],
         'B1': [(1, ('a', 'b')), (2, ('a', 'b')), (3, ('c', 'd'))]}}
```